# TypeError in Django after attempting to write data to MySQL using Django Models

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models

I am trying to write data to MySQL DB using models in django but I am getting TypeError. I have failed to identify the problem. I have attached the errot summary, traceback and the lines of code generating the bug. Please help me identify the problem

```
TypeError at /httptester/670747/

'str' object is not callable

Request Method:     POST Request URL:   http://127.0.0.1:8000/httptester/670747/ Django Version:    1.5.12 Exception Type:  TypeError Exception Value:  

'str' object is not callable

Exception Location:     /home/ronchino/deltasms/entry.py in handle, line 59 Python Executable:  /home/ronchino/deltasms-venv/bin/python Python Version:     2.7.3 Python Path:  

['/home/ronchino/deltasms',  '/home/ronchino/deltasms-venv/lib/python2.7',  '/home/ronchino/deltasms-venv/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',  '/home/ronchino/deltasms-venv/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',  '/home/ronchino/deltasms-venv/lib/python2.7/lib-old',  '/home/ronchino/deltasms-venv/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',  '/usr/lib/python2.7',  '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',  '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',  '/home/ronchino/deltasms-venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages']

Server time:    Mon, 26 Jan 2015 10:14:12 -0600

TRACEBACK Environment:


Request Method: POST Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/httptester/670747/

Django Version: 1.5.12 Python Version: 2.7.3 Installed Applications: ('model',  'django.contrib.auth',  'django.contrib.contenttypes',  'django.contrib.sessions',  'django.contrib.sites',  'django.contrib.messages',  'django.contrib.staticfiles',  'django.contrib.admin',  'django_nose',  'django_tables2',  'selectable',  'south',  'rapidsms',  'rapidsms.backends.database',  'rapidsms.contrib.handlers',  'rapidsms.contrib.httptester',  'rapidsms.contrib.messagelog',  'rapidsms.contrib.messaging',  'rapidsms.contrib.registration',  'rapidsms.contrib.default') Installed Middleware: ('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',  'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',  'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',  'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',  'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',  'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


Traceback: File "/home/ronchino/deltasms-venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  113.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) File "/home/ronchino/deltasms-venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  25.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs) File "/home/ronchino/deltasms-venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rapidsms/contrib/httptester/views.py" in message_tester
  70.                     storage.store_and_queue(identity, cd["text"]) File "/home/ronchino/deltasms-venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rapidsms/contrib/httptester/storage.py" in store_and_queue
  39.     receive(text, connection) File "/home/ronchino/deltasms-venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rapidsms/router/api.py" in receive
  40.     router.receive_incoming(message) File "/home/ronchino/deltasms-venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rapidsms/router/blocking/router.py" in receive_incoming
  124.         self.process_incoming(msg) File "/home/ronchino/deltasms-venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rapidsms/router/blocking/router.py" in process_incoming
  135.         continue_processing = self.process_incoming_phases(msg) File "/home/ronchino/deltasms-venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rapidsms/router/blocking/router.py" in process_incoming_phases
  165.                     handled = func(msg) File "/home/ronchino/deltasms-venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rapidsms/contrib/handlers/app.py" in handle
  33.             if handler.dispatch(self.router, msg): File "/home/ronchino/deltasms-venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rapidsms/contrib/handlers/handlers/pattern.py" in dispatch
  74.         cls(router, msg).handle(*match.groups()) File "/home/ronchino/deltasms/entry.py" in handle
  59.             p2 = entry(full_name=fullname.title(), mobile_number=sender, address=address.title(), citytown=cityortown.title(), creation_datetime=date, combination=combination, entry_code=entryref)

Exception Type: TypeError at /httptester/670747/ Exception Value: 'str' object is not callable
```

CODE:

```
entry = '%32x' % random.getrandbits(32*5)
entryref = 'ENT' + entry[2] + entry [4] + entry[6] + entry[8] + entry [10] + entry[12] + entry[14] + entry [16] + entry[18] + entry[20]

#Add entry
try:
    p2 = entry(full_name=fullname.title(), mobile_number=sender, address=address.title(), citytown=cityortown.title(), creation_datetime=date, combination=combination, entry_code=entryref)
    p2.save()
```

Comment: what are you trying to do ? clearly, `entry ` is a string.. then you are calling entry as a function

Comment: may also want to post your model and the full code for the view.